# I'm pretty smashing!

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

Here's an extremely short one for you guys- it's undergone quite a few revisions to be as unambiguous as possible!

> *Take me to any match and I'll be sure to win,*
>
> *for I am a bright-eyed and humble harlequin.*

Note:

> There is not a video game tag here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is it

> A peacock mantis shrimp (harlequin mantis shrimp) because they smash stuff with their claws and have really good eyesight (seeing colors we cant)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odontodactylus_scyllarus

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Your original answer (edited by @Mxracer424) didn't have [spoilers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers). It's a good idea to add >! to any part of your answer that might give it away in case someone else is trying to guess the answer. Why not [take the tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) for an easy badge.

Comment: That would be the answer I intended! Welcome to Puzzling, and good job :)

Answer (score 3):

Is it...

> a diamond?

Take me to any ring and I'll be sure to win,

> Diamonds are set into rings

for I am a bright-eyed and humble harlequin.

> Alludes to its shiny and colorful aspect

Comment: I thought this too. rot13(Uneyrdhva vf va qvnzbaq funcrq cnggreaf hfhnyyl)

Comment: Sorry @iiiidk and Joe, I'm not sure I get it. I'm surely lacking some cultural background here. If my answer is good and my explanation is wrong, then I leave it to someone else to propose the same answer with another explanation and win the green mark ;-)

Comment: Your explanation fit relatively well with the answer you gave, although there is a different answer for this riddle- one that takes into account all parts of the post to their literal meaning. I definitely thank you for this answer, though! I took a risk in posting a short riddle, knowing full-well that it may be a negative sinkhole for me; seeing potential answers to my riddles is the most exciting part of being on this site!

Comment: And, of course, your answer is making the riddle revised to an improved state. You got me thinking on the cultural part- the answer I know of is common knowledge to me, but I included a knowledge tag just in case!

Comment: @iiiidk $@$xhienne comments should be temporary and, once their message has been received, should be deleted unless there's some overriding reason to keep them around.  We don't want comments to pile up into conversations. Please take a moment to remove comments that are no longer needed.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be

> Beer

I'm pretty smashing

> Beer can be smashing if enough is consumed.

Take me to any match and I'll be sure to win

> Throw beer at a lit match and it'll win. Beer is typically 95% water and 5% alcohol, not enough for combustion.

for I am a bright-eyed

> Beer caps can be shiny and colorful. Also, the liquid is bright when light hits it.

and humble harlequin.

> can be in colorful bottles.

Comment: Since it was initially "any ring" and is now "any match" I don't think there is any wordplay on the word "match"

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> A firework ?

Take me to any match and I'll be sure to win,

> A firework is lit with a match to celebrate victory (Prise de la Bastille in France, Independance Day in the US)

for I am a bright-eyed and humble harlequin.

> The center of the explosion is very bright, and fireworks are colorful

Title: I'm pretty smashing!

> Refers to the noise a firework makes

Answer (score 0):

You might be

> Novak Djokovic

Take me to any match and I'll be sure to win,

> He used to be #1, currently #21 in the world, which means he'd probably win a tennis match against anybody (minus the top 20)

for I am a bright-eyed and humble harlequin.

> Dunno about bright-eyed...maybe he just has nice eyes?
> And one of his nicknames is "The Joker", which is like a harlequin (or at least tends to associate with them)

Title: I'm pretty smashing!

> A smash is an overhead tennis shot